# Reset popupmenu between the selections in MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, animation, popupmenu

I am trying to plot an animation using animatedline function and also controlling the speed of the animation using popupmenu. (such as 1/2x,1x,2x,4x etc).

I don't have any problem to create my animations in different speed.

The problem is , for example when I click "case 3" it starts to plot the animation and when I click case 4 (without waiting the end of the animation of case 3) it creates new one (case 4). Until this time still I don't have any problem. However, when "case 4" is ended the previous selection is going on (case 3). I want to figure out this issue. What I want is it should forget the previous one once I make a new selection.

I attached my code in below.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

```
 switch get(handles.threeDOF_animation_speed,'Value')  
    case 1       
    case 2
        run('threeDOF_create_animation.m')
        set(handles.button_3DOF_save_gif,'Enable','on')
     case 3

        run('threeDOF_create_animation.m')
        set(handles.button_3DOF_save_gif,'Enable','on')
    case 4
        run('threeDOF_create_animation.m')
        set(handles.button_3DOF_save_gif,'Enable','on')
     case 5
        run('threeDOF_create_animation.m')
        set(handles.button_3DOF_save_gif,'Enable','on')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

it sounds to me you need a reset first for every plot you are making. So use a clear on the axis when you click on the button first and then make it run the animation.

```
function ClearLinesFromAxes()
  axesHandlesToChildObjects = findobj(gca, 'Type', 'line');
  if ~isempty(axesHandlesToChildObjects)
    delete(axesHandlesToChildObjects);
  end  
  return; % from ClearLinesFromAxes
```

Source:
https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/21006-how-to-erase-a-line

also what might work:

```
You probably want cla(), but perhaps you want clf()
```

Source: https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/40925-how-to-clear-a-plot-in-gui

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am already using cla and I tried your other suggestions. But they did not work.

Comment: Could you be more clear as to what is happening when using the solutions? And on to what is not happening and mayb add some screenshots? :).

Comment: Oh ok, when I used clf it clear not only plot it clear all figure screen. So, using cla is works to clear plot at the beginning. Here is a gif file of my plot. When 4x plot was completed, it continue to 2x case.
https://imgur.com/x0GriNw

Comment: ah you might need to cancel the animation that was running before. 
The behaviour is now as following:
Run A
Clear screen
Run B
Run remainder of A
A should be cancelled. how? google stop animation matlab not sure which command should be used.

Comment: I'm not sure how the m files work, but I think you might want to look at something like this: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/218432-stop-the-execution-of-a-function-with-a-push-button-guide